# Example of Drools Excel decision table that uses METADATA column?

Tags: excel, metadata, drools

Can anyone point me towards one of these ? I've downloaded the 5.5 distro and walked through the examples  but cannot find what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra column (or many columns as you want), put `METADATA` value for these columns at the same row as `CONDITION` and `ACTION` value row. Here is a example:

assuming it is at #10 row, you define `CONDITION` and `ACTION`. And now you want to add `@myTag01` and `@myTag02` 2 custom attributes.

1. columns: Let's uses column D and E (Don't break RuleSet, RuleTable overall layout)
2. row10: set `D10=METADATA` and `E10=METADATA`
3. row11: Leave these values empty for these `METADATA` columns at the next row, i.e. cell D11, E11 are empty.
4. row12: set D12=`myTag01("@param")` and E12=`myTag02("@param")`, and please note `@` is ignored here.
5. row13: D13 is the description of myTag01, E13 is the description is `myTag02`, e.g. D13=`My First Tag`, E13=`My Second Tag`
6. row14...: Starting from D14 and E14, it is tag value you need to put there. E.g. D14=`tag01ValX`, E14=`tag02ValY`, it will generated `@myTag01("tag01ValX")` and `@myTag02("tag02ValY")`